# CSS :not(li>:first-child) selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of elements:

```
<ul>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coffee
    <ul>
      <li>White Coffee</li>
      <li>Black Coffee</li>
      <li>Coffee Low Caffein</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

I want to style like this:

```
ul li:not(li>:first-child)
{
    color:red;
}

ul li>:first-child
{
    color:blue;
}
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M329D/), but it's not working with selector `ul li:not(li>:first-child)`. I want a final result like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBRcr/), any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you just use the code in the second fiddle? Also I don't think `:first-child` does what you think it does.

Comment: You can also just do `body > ul > li { color:red; }`.

Comment: @BoltClock, The second fiddle with blue color is replace red color. I don't want it, i have complite css rules and i want it styled one by one.

Comment: @IdhamPerdameian then just add a specific class to each `li`.

Comment: You can use only simple selectors inside :not()  
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation

Comment: @joespina i go to think about it.

Comment: The selectors `ul li:not(:first-child)` and `ul li:first-child` are syntactically correct versions of your selectors. But [they don’t look the same](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/CQhyR/) as your desired result. I still don’t understand what’s wrong with your second fiddle – what do you mean by “[i want it styled one by one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172772/css-notlifirst-child-selector#comment26624714_18172772)”?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul id="first">
```

For first level of `li`

```
ul > li
{
    color:red;
}
```

For any other `li` thereafter..

```
ul#first > li li
{
    color:blue;
}
```

Updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/M329D/9/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused, but in cases where I want a first-child to have a different style, I actually give it's siblings the desired alternative style:

```
li {
  color:#00f;
}
li + li {
  color:#f00;
}
```

Comment: in what sense? Can you elaborate? There's not much to try... but based on the OP's not quite clear question, my answer is apt.

Comment: Check this part of the question "I want final result like this fiddle" and compare the output if you use your CSS code.

Comment: good point. the selector in the original post threw me compared to the question (minus the example fiddle).

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li:not(:first-child)
{
    color:red;
}

ul li:first-child
{
    color:blue;
}
```